# Exclude a folder from wordpress installed in a subfolder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, directory, subdirectory

I have installed wordpress in public_html/newsite

I have made a simple html page inside public_html/newsite/myfolder/page.html

I need to enter to www.mysite.com.ar/myfolder/page.html but I get 404 page.

I tried this inside public_html/newsite

```
    ##################################
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /newsite/
# RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ./myfolder /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(myfolder).*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /newsite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
##################################
```

but it doesnt work.
I also put it in root (inside public_html)

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve this with a redirect:

```
 Redirect 301 /myfolder/page.html  www.mysite.com.ar/newsite/myfolder/page.html
```

But is better to rethink your url estructure. Do you really need to put your wordpress into '/newsite/'?